# Relations with another table using Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, yii

how I can use array in cell related with another table in database like ?

**Users table:**

```
Name | languages_id
Anas | 1,2,3
```

**Languages table:**

```
id | language
1  | English
2  | Arabic
```

it’s work or not ?! and do you know what can I use in yii to do this ?

Comment: It is better to create a new table `UserLanguages` with `UserId` and `LanguageId` and remove the `languageid` from the users table.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal ... And create an "id" field in the Users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.

Don't store mutiple items as comma separated column, [**it is really bad**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).

You should keep your tables [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), by creating a new table `UsersLanguages` as a many to many table between the `USERS` and `Languages` table. Somrthing like this:

**`Users`**:

- `UserId`,
- `UserName`,
- ... other details.

**`Languages`:**

- `LanguageId`,
- `LanguageName`,
- ...

**`UserLanguages`**:

- `UserId` foreign key references `Users(UserId)`,
- `LanguageId` foreign kery references `Languages(LanguageId)`.

Comment: @Anas This approach is better regardless the front end application you are using, and it will make the work required from you more easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT
    name,
    language
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN
    languages ON FIND_IN_SET(languages.id, languages_id) != 0
GROUP BY
    name
```

Although Mahmoud Gamal's comment would perhaps be the better way to go about it.